# What framework should I use in my manifest file

Tags: application-development

I'm writing an application for Ubuntu for Phones and need to know what framework goes in the manifest.json file. I submitted an app but got this back:-

```
'ubuntu-sdk-13.10' is obsolete. Please use a newer framework
```

What are the supported frameworks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see the up-to-date list of supported frameworks here: https://docs.google.com/a/canonical.com/spreadsheets/d/1t_JGpg4r8BLluzfzmqa-gAbcKUjKUOufSCTSdPpFc5g/edit

Answer (score -2):

Supported frameworks are :-

`'ubuntu-sdk-14.04-dev1'
'ubuntu-sdk-14.04-qml-dev1'
'ubuntu-sdk-14.04-html-dev1'`

I was also facing the same issue, and 'ubuntu-sdk-14.04-dev1' worked for me.
But remember, if you are changing framework to 14.04 in manifest.json file then you must have to change 'policy_version' from 1 to 1.1 in (projectName).json file.

do not forget to make this change otherwise it wont work.

Comment: This is out of date.